# \mkbibquote does not close quotation marks if immediately followed by colon

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, csquotes

The following biblatex record (embedded within a minimal LaTeX example):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
Author = {Craft, Robert},
Title = {Stravinsky at His \mkbibquote{Bird-Best}: Robert Craft Untangles the Tales Surrounding the Creation of \foreignlanguage{french}{\mkbibemph{Le rossignol}}},
Journaltitle = {Opera News},
Date = {1982},
Volume = {46},
Number = {8},
Pages = {14-15, 34}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autostyle=true, english=american, french=guillemets, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[french, german, american]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{test1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

is incorrectly rendered by `pdflatex` as:

> Robert Craft, “Stravinsky at His ‘Bird-Best: Robert Craft Untangles the Tales Surrounding the Creation of *Le rossignol*,’” *Opera News*, 1982, no. 8, 14–15, 34.

Note that the closing quotation mark after Bird-Best is missing.

With `lualatex`, however, there is no such issue. The reference is formatted correctly:

> Robert Craft, “Stravinsky at His ‘Bird-Best’: Robert Craft Untangles the Tales Surrounding the Creation of *Le rossignol*,” *Opera News*, 1982, no. 8, 14–15, 34.

I have tried all the latest stable and development branches of `biblatex`, including 2.9a and 3.0. The issue is likely related to `csquotes`?

PLK, `biblatex` author, and I have already discussed this on GitHub (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/259), but we have so far been unable to track down the cause.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Confirming that the patch posted by @JosephWright at the github link above resolves the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case outlined `biblatex` uses a macro called `\blx@usqcheck` which it uses for US-style quotations with 'moving' punctuation. This checks ahead for punctuation, spaces and so on but also includes a check:

```
\if\noexpand\@let@token\relax
  \blx@usqcheck@i\blx@tempb
\fi
```

where the `\blx@usqcheck@i\blx@tempb` does not insert any closing quote mark but saves if for future use. (There are a couple of internal branches sharing the above code, hence it not be immediately obvious.)

The original author of `biblatex` leaves us no notes as to what this code was meant to do, but I think he was aiming to allow an explicit `\relax` to be used to prevent moving punctuation

```
\mkbibquote{some odd text}\relax ,
```

The problem is that the construct `\if\noexpand\foo\relax` is true if `\foo` is a macro at all, not just if it is equal in meaning to `\relax`. (The `\noexpand` primitive makes `\foo` temporarily equal to `\relax` if it is a macro but not if say you've done `\let\foo=a`.)

That leads us to the problem. When pdfTeX is in use and the `french` option has been given for `babel`, the character `:` is 'active' and has a macro definition *even if the active language is not French*. Thus the test in `biblatex` goes the 'wrong way': it finds a macro following the quote, thinks this is a relax and skips the closing punctuation. That doesn't happen with LuaTeX as it doesn't use an active `:` for French typography, so the issue never shows up.

The fix I've suggested is to add a second test in the right place: as a short patch

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@usqcheck#1#2{%
  \def\blx@tempa{#1}%
  \def\blx@tempb{#2}%
  \ifx\@let@token\space
    \blx@usqcheck@i\blx@tempa
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
    \blx@usqcheck@i\blx@tempa
  \fi
  \if\noexpand\@let@token\relax
    \ifx\relax\@let@token
      \blx@usqcheck@i\blx@tempb
    \fi
  \fi
  \expandafter\blx@usqcheck@ii\blx@quotepunct\relax&}

\def\blx@usqcheck@i#1#2&{\fi#1}
\makeatother
```

This now checks that the *meaning* of the following macro starts with `\relax`. There are still cases that might go wrong, but for the moment this seems like the 'lowest risk' fix. As I say, what is lacking is a note on why this test is there: it's not immediately obvious what the reasoning is!

Comment: This is now implemented in the 3.0 dev version.